# Статистика за документами/контрагентами чи статистика по контрагентах, контрагентам?

Tags: вибір-слова, росіянізм

Як правильно сказати?

> Статистика за контрагентами, статистика за документами

чи

> Статистика по документах, статистика по контрагентах

Наскільки я знаю то в орудному відмінку ми використовуємо сполучник "за" , типу "по" росіянізм, але всеж я ніколи не чув такого формулювання.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko  а якщо оце уточнення і так зрозуміло з контексту і не хочеться його повторювати?

Answer (score 3):

#### Статистика

Статистика. Навчальний посібник. Миколаїв. МНАУ. 2016.

> Поняття статистики є багатозначним, а саме:
>
> - це спеціальна наукова і навчальна дисципліна;
> - це практична діяльність: збір, систематизація, обробка та аналіз статистичних даних;
> - це сукупність цифрових зведень, що характеризують явище,чи сукупність;
> - це статистичний критерій – правило за яким формуються відповідні висновки.
>
> Таким чином, статистика – це наука, і одночасно один із способів
>   управління. Ці дві функції статистики постійно взаємодіють.

З етимологічного боку це status «стан, громадянський стан; забезпеченість, добробут».

[Стати́стика](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) - «облік масових явищ; наука, що вивчає кількісну сторону масових явищ»

#### Прийменник ЗА чи ПО

> [Прийменник](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) - незмінне службове слово, що вказує на синтаксичне
>   підпорядкування іменника, а також займенника і числівника.

Вживання прийменників [за](http://l-ponomar.com/kultura-movy-vzhyvannya-pryjmennyka-za-krok-odynadtsyatyj/) та [по](http://l-ponomar.com/kultura-movy-vzhyvannya-pryjmennyka-po-krok-tretij/) доволі добре описані в мережі. І в горосі теж є [за](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B0) і [по](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D0%BE).

#### Я теж маю слово

В запитанні потрібно обрати один з прийменників, який краще влаштовує. Але суть у тому, що лише автор зможе в даному випадку правильно підібрати прийменник та вказати зв’язок між словами. Бо лише йому відомо, про який зв’язок йде мова. Можна лише гадати про цей зв’язок.

І схоже, що автор не розуміє різниці між за та по. Тож потрібно пояснити цю різницю.

Пропоную автору запитання спочатку дослідити та зрозуміти де, коли і який з прийменників потрібно використовувати і повідомити: що саме має на увазі. Або ж потрібно уточнити запитання і навести детальніші приклади.

#### Моє розуміння вказаних прикладів

Своє розуміння і намагання повідомити про необхідність уточнення вказав в непочутому коментарі раніше:

> Переконаний, що дані речі можна назвати точніше. Адже статистика щось
>   описує. В статистиці є не лише документи чи контрагенти. Статистика
>   скоріше описує якусь певну дію чи кількість подій цих документів чи
>   контрагентів. І, мабуть, точнішим будуть вирази типу "Статистика
>   частоти запрошень контрагентів" чи "Статистика щоденної кількості
>   виписаних документів". У вашому випадку можна багато як сказати, якщо
>   не знати деталі, наприклад, просто "статистика документів" чи
>   "статистика контрагентів".

Якщо ж відкинути точність, то потрібно слово "статистика" використовувати як слова наука, або як результат обліку (або дані, або інформація). Це випливає з опису значень слова статистика. І переконаний, що результат влаштує краще.

Отже маємо такі варіянти:

- результат щодо контрагентів - дані щодо контрагентів - статистика щодо контрагентів - статистика щодо документів;
- інформація про контрагентів - статистика про контрагентів - статистика про документи;
- результат обліку контрагентів - статистика контрагентів (хоча тут справді збігається, наче власниками статистики є контрагенти), статистика документів.

Як і казав: можна лише гадати.

Обирайте яке значення вкладали у це словосполучення і правда закохає кривду.

#### Варіянт ухилення

Також можна позбути текст від слова "статистика". Тобто зробити заголовком інформації "Статистика". А нижче описати щось типу: "Графік росту кількості контрагентів", "Таблиця незаповнених документів". Але все прямує до уточнень.

Answer (score 2):

Розгляньмо всі варіанти прийменників.

### Прийменник "По"

---

**Прийменник "по" сам собою не є русизмом і є абсолютно легітимним прийменником, але його використанням в українській є обмеженим і на практиці, зазвичай, є неправильним, оскільки форми і способи використання часто запозичуються із російської.**

Звертаючись до [OC](https://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%BE/) бачимо, що прийменник "*по*" часто вживається недоречно і неправильно в українській мові. В дуже багатьох джерелах рекомендують його змінювати на інші прийменники, наприклад [це відео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxqnhgD-1CU).
Також про це написано в [блозі Людмили Пономаренко](http://l-ponomar.com/kultura-movy-vzhyvannya-pryjmennyka-po-krok-tretij/), де вона пропонує його змінювати на інші прийменники:

> Сьогодні у нас мова про вживання прийменника ПО (на жаль, дуже
>   горезвісного), який в українській мові вживається досить рідко, а в
>   російській, навпаки, дуже часто. В цьому й полягає причина
>   «інтервенції» нав’язливого прийменника ПО в українську мову й
>   поглиблення в ній процесу «суржикізації».

Таким чином, на основі вищезазначених джерел можна стверджувати, що прийменник "по" у авторській конструкції вживається **неправильно**.

Крім того, необхідно зазначити, що закінчення місцевого відмінка іменника або прикметника після прийменника "по" має бути в місцевому(-ах,-ях), а не в давальному відмінку(-ам,-ям).

[image: Правильне вживання прийменника "по"]

Цей факт також підтверджує ["Мова - ДНК нації"](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/orfografiya/po-skladax-chu-po-skladam).
Рухаємося далі через можливі прийменники.

---

### Прийменники, які можуть бути заміною "по"

---

*"через", "в/у", "на", "для", "за", "з", "щодо"*, *безприйменникова конструкція* - можливі легітимні варіанти заміни "*по*"<sup>Л.П.</sup>.

"через", "в/у", "на", "для" можна відразу відсіяти, бо вони суперечать правилам фонетики або яскраво суперечать закономірностям вживання<sup>Л.П.</sup>.

Далі на основі обгрунтувань<sup>Л.П.</sup> робимо висновки.

1. *"за"* може підходити, бо він використовується, коли мова йде про якийсь
   **принцип, критерій, ознаку**<sup>Л.П.</sup>, я розумію, що категорія в цьому контексті є/може бути критерієм.(*Суб'єктивізм*)
2. *"з"* <sup>Л.П.</sup> має право на існування, проте і для доведення, і для заперечення в мене недостатньо аргументів, оскільки певних закономірностей немає<sup>Л.П.</sup>, лише здогади.
3. *Безприйменникова конструкція* суперечить закономірностям вживання<sup>Л.П.</sup>. Крім того, статистика контрагентів звучить ніби статистика була зроблена контрагентами, тому я був би схильний виключити цей варіант.(*Суб'єктивізм*)
4. *"щодо"*

   > У [..] прикладах з прийменником "щодо" йдеться про певний стосунок до
   >   якоїсь справи.

   [image: "щодо" showcase]
   В даному випадку, ця закономірність не дотримана повністю, оскільки контрагенти/документи не є певною справою, а радше категорією/стороною.

---

*Джерела:*

   <sub>Л.П. -  [Рубрика Людмили Пономаренко "Культура мови: вживання прийменника ПО (Крок третій)" у власному блозі](http://l-ponomar.com/kultura-movy-vzhyvannya-pryjmennyka-po-krok-tretij/), [Культура мови: вживання прийменника ЗА (Крок одинадцятий)](http://l-ponomar.com/kultura-movy-vzhyvannya-pryjmennyka-za-krok-odynadtsyatyj/)

   OC - [OnlineCorrector.com.ua, "Вживання прийменника ПО"](https://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%BE/).

   МДН - [Сайт "Мова - ДНК Нації"](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/orfografiya/po-skladax-chu-po-skladam)</sub>

Comment: Ви зробили ретельний аналіз, але, НМД, зробили неправильний висновок. «Статистика за/по контрагентах/м» означає «статистика по **кожному** контрагенту»: тобто, контрагент1=100грн, контрагент2=500грн і т.д. Тобто, перелічення множини (контрагентів) по одному. Таким чином, «рахувати **по** пальцях», «читати **по** складах» здається найкращою аналогією.

Comment: НМД? Що це? Ви могли б пояснити, що це за правило із *кожним*? Я дивився в Л.П. тут https://imgur.com/a/lDKZ1Sn і не побачив жодного валідного варіанту для контрагентів/документів. Ви маєте на увазі, що це міра/кількість?

Comment: НМД = на мою думку. :) Що стосується мого тлумачення словосполучення «статистика за/по контрагентам/х» — ну от самі відповідьте на питання — що це словосполучення означає на практиці? Мені здається, що це перелічення елементів множини, один за одним. Чи є інші тлумачення?

Comment: Необов'язково, я трактував це слово так - "статистика ПРИЙМЕННИК (**всіх**) контрагентів". Крім того, навіть, якщо це перелічення елементів множини, один за одним, як воно корелюється із Л.П. https://imgur.com/a/lDKZ1Sn Які у вас аргументи щодо переваги саме варіанту "по"? Мені цікаво це, бо я, можливо, теж не маю рації і буде чудово, якщо ми зможемо сформувати більш канонічну відповідь.

Comment: «всіх» = «всіх сумарно разом» або «всіх» = «кожного окремо»? Я ж кажу, треба зʼясувати фізичний сенс словосполучення, інакше буде неможливо встановити суб'єктні відносини між словами «статистика» і «контрагент». Якими ці відносини є, з вашої точки зору? Для мене ці відносини — перелічення елементів множини.

Comment: «всіх» = «всіх сумарно разом».

Comment: Ага. «Статистика контрагентів» = статистика усіх контрагентів, взятих сумарно разом. Одне число. А «річна статистика» = статистика усіх років сумарно разом? Тобто, «річна статистика державного боргу України» = одне-єдине число, яке містить суму усіх державних боргів України, починаючи з Рюриковичів?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103002/discussion-between-improbable-and-bytebuster).

Comment: bytebuster, перепрошую, але тут змушений з вами не погодитися, бо маю освіту саме з економічної статистики. Статистика будь-чого - це завжди довжелезні таблиці, фактично, набори даних, які обробленому виді іноді можуть бути перетворені у графіки для наглядності. Не існує "річної статистики", якщо не на дні ріки, але існує річний баланс і навіть там будуть дві зведені цифри. От подивіться https://ukrstat.org/operativ/oper_new_rus.html

Answer (score 0):

**Прийменник ЗА**

Зазвичай при перекладі з російської вживають прийменник **за** щоб уникнути кальки. Але існує багато особливостей його вживання, зокрема [способів заміни](http://l-ponomar.com/kultura-movy-vzhyvannya-pryjmennyka-za-krok-odynadtsyatyj/) ненормативних висловів та нормативних словосполучень в українській мові.

Щоб зрозуміти яку саме конструкцію краще використати, слід завжди виходити з контексту.

**Статистика за контрагентами, статистика за документами** - так не можна сказати. **Статистика** можемо замінити на **отримані дані**, в такому випадку єдиною правильною буде конструкція:

Статистика, **що відповідає документам** які були надані вами раніше та наявні дані **по контрагентах** на кінець облікового періоду не співпадають.

Answer (score -1):

В російській мові і в нелітературній українській конструкції на «по» вживаються надзвичайно широко (приклад з другої: «а ти по тому, шо я тебе просив, всьо зробив?»). В літературній українській натомість, так виглядає, треба в кожному випадку ретельно підбирати «свій» коректний варіант, бо автоматичного, калькуючого перекладу з російського ісходніка, лишень озброївшись «за» чи «з» (не забуваймо й «з») — не зробиш. Тобто, в літературній українській треба відходити від російської парадигми на «по» і робити так, як пропонує Андрій Іванченко.

Comment: Зверніть, будь ласка, увагу на те, що я писав [тут](/q/6071#comment9972_6078) (і [тут](/q/3270#comment9973_6080)).

Comment: Дуже суб'єктивно і багато помилок.